# UICollectionView layout with custom layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Is it possible to create a collection view with an item on the left and two items stacked to the right of it?

Whenever I specify the correct sizes to do this in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate I can only get one item on the right side and the other is displayed in the next row underneath.  I know I can do this with custom cells that contain more than one view (top and bottom) but I would like to know if its possible without that.  It would be a lot less complex if I could do it without the custom double view cell.  Im using a 'flow' layout with 'vertical' scroll direction (as per IB).

First image is what I hope to achieve and the second is what I am able to achieve currently.

[image: What I want to do]

[image: Whats happening]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass for this - [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1)